# FUNCTIONS : Theoretical Doubt

Tags: functions, notation

I am currently  learning calculus of one variables , and i have come across a symbol  $$f(x,y).$$

Can anybody explain the meaning of this ? Thanks!

Comment: It's a function of two variables.  For example $f(x,y)=y\sqrt{x}$ means that $f(1,2)=2\sqrt{1}=2$.

Comment: Rather than one number sent to one number --- such as $f(x)=x^2$ sends $x=3$ to $f(x)=3^2=9$ --- it is a pair of numbers sent to a single number. For example, the area of a rectangle function which takes the pair $(x,y)=(\text{height},\text{width})$ to $xy$ and we write $f(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: and if i use the symbol $f(x,0)$ , does it mean this function takes only one input ?

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: \>A\to B$ is a law that produces for each input "point" $x\in A$ an output value $y\in B$ according to some formula (or geometrical,  verbal, algorithmical, $\ldots$ description). The output value is denoted by $f(x)$.

Here $A$ and $B$ can be arbitrary nonempty sets; but in any case there is an agreed on format to identify the individual elements of $A$ resp. $B$.

Sometimes the *domain* $A$ of $f$ is a subset of the $(x,y)$-plane ${\mathbb R}^2$. An individual element of $A$, a point $p$ in the plane, is then addressed by its coordinates $(x,y)$. In such a case one omits one set of parentheses and writes $f(x,y)$ instead of $f\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$. Anyway, a function defined on such a "truly two-dimensional" $A$ is called a *function of two variables*, even though each individual  input is a single point $p$ in the plane.